# Combining points and polygons in Qgis

Tags: qgis, point, line

I´m trying to create a map that can be loaded into the program CityEngine as a shapefile.

To create this map I have an excel spreadsheet that includes locations, in longitude and Lattitude, and some information regarding the building at that location. I have been able to make the points appear in the right location in Qgis, when they are imported in the CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS84). I then save the points as a shapefile.

After that I have exported the DWG file as a DXF file by using AutoCAD and imported it into Qgis using a custom CRS which I read would keep the scale and avoid the DXF to be "bend" around the world.

+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

After placing the DXF I export it as a shapefile with the CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS84),  and open a new project and place both the points, and the lines. The problem is that I have to move the lines very long to be located in the right location compared to the points. The building footprints are not located precisely under the points. I have to move the points by hand, which in my understanding is not a good thing, it makes me think that somewhere something is no longer the right dimensions. I made some measurements of the polygons and they seem to be the right dimensions, but the shape should fit under the points. When turning on the open street map from the OpenLayers plugin everything gets even more wrong.

I'm having problems understanding if this is the right way or anybody has any advice on how to transfer the information from the excel ark onto the polygons and then export it as a shapefile.

Comment: What software do have that uses .dwg?  if it's Autocad then .dxf can be opened straight into qgis, but the related data won't be with it.  otherwise you'll have to create the shapefile in autocad.  The height data is easy, just save as csv and join to the polylines once you've worked that bit out.

Comment: "Everything gets even more wrong" is an excellent description of what the OpenLayers plugin will do to a project. Use QuickMapServices instead. And make sure on-the-fly transformation is turned on.